# Axios PUT Request not updating state properly

Tags: reactjs, api, axios, crud

In `EditContact` a user updates their current contacts. The submit button for the `EditContact` form sends an axios request to update the contact and change the state. However, when it changes state it doesnt cause a re-render and I have to refresh the page to see the change. My response from the put request is sending back the updated data as well but something is wrong with my `setContacts` possibly. Ive tried to set the state without using a callback as well and setting it with the return array from the map function. Also, I set the `setContacts` to an empty array in the `editContactHandler` and that does cause the re-render.

App.js

```
function App() {
  const [contacts, setContacts] = useState([]);

  const editContactHandler = async (contact) => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.put(
        `http://localhost:3006/contacts/${contact.id}`,
        contact
      );
      setContacts((prevContacts) =>
        prevContacts.map((prevContact) => {
          return prevContact.id === contact.id ? response.data : prevContact;
        })
      );
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

EditContact.js

```
const EditContact = (props) => {
  const params = useParams();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    id: params.id,
    firstName: '',
    lastName: '',
    email: '',
  });

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    setFormData((prevFormData) => ({ ...prevFormData, [name]: value }));
  };

  const handleUpdate = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (formData.firstName === '' || formData.email === '') {
      alert('All fields are mandatory');
      return;
    }
    props.editContactHandler(formData);
    setFormData({ id: params.id, firstName: '', lastName: '', email: '' });
    navigate('/');
  };
```

Comment: Is there any page you are displaying your whole record of contacts?

Comment: I have a fake server setup thats running on my localhost. I also have an AddContact feature that is working fine and updating correctly but this is what it looks like in db.json      {
  "contacts": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "firstName": "Christian",
      "lastName": "Bale",
      "email": "i_am_batman@yahoo.com"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "firstName": "Lil",
      "lastName": "Wayne",
      "email": "weezybaby@gmail.com"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "firstName": "Will",
      "lastName": "Smith",
      "email": "willsmith@gmail.com"
    }
  ]
}

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following solution might help you :

You should have edit Button, whenever the user clicks that edit button following code should run :

```
 const editContactHandler =(contact) => {
      setContacts((prevContacts) =>
        prevContacts.map((prevContact) => {
          return prevContact.id === contact.id ? response.data : prevContact;
        })
    }
  };
```

Also if user change any data and clicks the Save/submit button, then this should happen :

```
const submitEditContact = async (id) => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.put(
        `http://localhost:3006/contacts/${id}`,
        contact
      );
     
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

You should consider change and save as separate functions.

Comment: I dont see how 2 buttons would solve this problem though

Comment: Your state should be updated first and then you save updated state to your database. if your user doesn't change any data your code even then calling API and it's not a common practice. Also I have shared my personal approach of doing Edit function, and hope that it may solve  your problem.

Comment: I figured it out just now. My params.id is a string but on my server its a number. All i had to do was set id: Number(params.id) in my form to have the state re-render but ty for trying to help me out. I do appreciate you taking your time to respond and help find a solution